# Different color line with plotpc in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting two plotpc charts (i want to see decision boundaries from perceptron and from Bayesian net) and I need them to have different color.

```
plotpv(P,T);
hold all;
plotpc(net.IW{1,1},0,'r');
plotpc([w1(maxind(1)), w2(maxind(2))],0,'g');
title('Decision boundaries');
```

However all my trials ended up with failure and I always get same colors like this:

[image]

Thank you for help.

Comment: Could you please add some sample data, so we could run the сode without having to guess the inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the output of `plotpc` (line handle) to some variable, which you can then use to alter line appearance, e.g.

```
hPlot = plotpc(net.IW{1,1},0);
set(hPlot, 'Color', 'r');
```

Also, I don't think `plotpc` accepts a color as a third argument - you should get a warning when you do that.

Comment: Yes, I got a warning. Anyway, this is working, thank you!